# Strip numbers from MySQL SELECT

Tags: mysql, string, select

I need to remove numbers from a name field in a SELECT query. The numbers are likely to be at the end of the string. Examples would be as follows:

```
Some Name
Namewithnospace
NamewithInt 100   <--- I want to remove this int from the string
```

I cannot guarantee that the first part of the string won't contain a space, although I can be fairly sure that the number will be the last part of the string. Also most of the data won't have a space.

I can see that there must be a solution using `REVERSE()` and `SUBSTRING()` but can't work out how not to mangle the data that either has no spaces, or those that have a space but no integer.

edit: below is the definition for the MySQL C function that Ollie pointed me towards, with a change made by me to the regexp (to include spaces and punctuation in the function's output):

```
DELIMITER !

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS alphas! 

CREATE FUNCTION alphas ( str VARCHAR(255) ) 
               RETURNS VARCHAR(255) 
               DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  DECLARE i, len SMALLINT DEFAULT 1; 
  DECLARE ret VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT ''; 
  DECLARE c VARCHAR(1); 
  SET len = CHAR_LENGTH( str ); 
  REPEAT 
    BEGIN 
      SET c = MID( str, i, 1 ); 
      IF c REGEXP '[[:alpha:]]' OR c REGEXP '[[:space:]]' THEN 
        SET ret=CONCAT(ret,c); 
      END IF; 
      SET i = i + 1; 
    END; 
  UNTIL i > len END REPEAT; 
  RETURN ret; 
END !
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Will there always be a space just before the digits?

Comment: There's really no 100% safe or foolproof way to do what you're asking. Any solution will be a hack. It would be better/easier to modify what data is allowed in the field and prevent data like the above from ever being entered in the first place.

Comment: Could you please clarify your requirement?  Do you want to remove all numeric digits from the result column?  Or do you want only to remove any sequence of one or more numeric digits from the end of the column?  What do you want to do about trailing spaces, either after the numeric digits, or after the remaining data once the numeric digits are removed?  Once you get your specification right, you'll probably be able to write a stored function or other MySQL incantation to do the right thing.

Comment: @OllieJones Yes I would like to run a SELECT that includes all of the text, but none of the integers. Also would trim any trailing whitespaces.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Unfortunately not possible, the data capture interface is 3rd party :-(

Comment: @ypercube no, there may not be a space before the digits. Mostly there will but can't guarantee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make yourself this stored function called `alphas`.  It goes through the characters of its input text string one by one and removes all the digits.

```
DELIMITER !

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS alphas! 

CREATE FUNCTION alphas ( str VARCHAR(255) ) 
                   RETURNS VARCHAR(255) 
                   DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  DECLARE i, len SMALLINT DEFAULT 1; 
  DECLARE ret VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT ''; 
  DECLARE c VARCHAR(1);   /* NOT CHAR!  NOT CHAR! NOT CHAR! */ 
  SET len = CHAR_LENGTH( str ); 
  REPEAT 
    BEGIN 
      SET c = MID( str, i, 1 ); 
      IF NOT c REGEXP '[[:digit:]]' THEN 
        SET ret=CONCAT(ret,c); 
      END IF; 
      SET i = i + 1; 
    END; 
  UNTIL i > len END REPEAT; 
  RETURN ret; 
END !
DELIMITER ;
```

Then do this.

```
 SELECT alphas(column) AS alphacolumn
```

Here's a useful resource from which I cribbed this function.
http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=815

Comment: that's a really nice solution Ollie - kudos! One thing I would like to do is preserve white spaces in the string, i.e. `some user 123` becomes `some user`. I can see I need to edit the regex, but not sure how to do this?

Comment: Have made some progress - have edited the regexp as follows: `IF c REGEXP '[[:alpha:]]' OR c REGEXP '[[:space:]]' THEN` but the output still excludes whitespaces: `SELECT alphas("foo bar");` results in `foobar`

Comment: ARRGH!  Bitten by the CHAR / VARCHAR thing again!  How often has that happened to me and still I never learn....  I just changed `DECLARE c CHAR(1);` to `DECLARE c VARCHAR(1);`  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That's great Ollie, thanks for getting back to me, that sorted it out. Couldn't see that for the life of me!

Answer (score 0):

If using an [UDF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-functions.html) is an option for you, there is a [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp) available. You can use it with the pattern `'[0-9]+$'` to remove the numbers.

Comment: that sounds interesting - I did see that there was limited REGEX support but couldn't fathom how to use it in a SELECT